# Trying to run Grails app in IntelliJ Idea fails with loader constraint violation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grails

When I try to run a legacy Grails 2.5.0 app that runs just fine on a colleague's machine, I get the following error:

`Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.getReloadableType(II)Lorg/springsource/loaded/ReloadableType;" the class loader (instance of groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader) of the current class, grails/plugin/cache/compiler/CacheTransformation, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/springsource/loaded/TypeRegistry, have different Class objects for the type org/springsource/loaded/ReloadableType used in the signature`

I understand it has to do with 2 different loaders trying to load the ReloadableType class from the springloaded library.  When I run n the commandline I get this error instead:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at _PluginDependencies$_run_closure2.doCall(_PluginDependencies.groovy:48)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at _GrailsPackage$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage.groovy:57)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:28)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
| Error Error loading plugin manager: null
```

Any thoughts?  I did a dependency report trying to resolve the first error, but I don't see anything that stands out to me.

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.8 build 291.

I managed to get it running on command line with a fresh repo clone.  The key was not trying to open it with IntelliJ Idea.  So it seems the process of creating a project from existing code is injecting something into the project that screws it up.